# Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 400. Truncated server response:

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-forms, data-entry

So i try to make an script on https://script.google.com/ to automate data entry from google spreadsheet to google forms but i always receiving this code error

```
"Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" class="m2"><head><link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="16x16" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/spreadsheets/forms/favic... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 25, file "Code")"
```

Can somebody help me?

Here My code

```
function auto_data_entry() {

  var formURL="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSduXRTFWkeq1ZLRaiGzhmT58oUZSp20FHsT73_qMj8ZpobuqA/formResponse";

  var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wrkSht= wrkBk.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var Transaction1 = wrkSht.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var Transaction2 = wrkSht.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var Transaction3 = wrkSht.getRange("A3").getValue();
  var Transaction4 = wrkSht.getRange("A4").getValue();
  var Transaction5 = wrkSht.getRange("A5").getValue();

  var datamap={"entry.663378019":Transaction1,
   "entry.978525821":Transaction2,
   "entry.1636658367":Transaction3,
   "entry.1490939339":Transaction4,
   "entry.2066528728":Transaction5};

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "payload": datamap
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(formURL, options);
}
```

And here the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-sLoKy6npftapr3QxoRIoYozBN6izei0E9uqF4yLg-8/edit?usp=sharing

And here was the form https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSduXRTFWkeq1ZLRaiGzhmT58oUZSp20FHsT73_qMj8ZpobuqA/viewform

Thanks!

Comment: May be the header is not valid!

Comment: Hi ! Are you the owner of that form?

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue here is that you are trying to use the fetch method for a google form. [Fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) works for making HTTP requests to websites so it will be overcomplicated to try to do this to a form as you would need to create a custom response on that side.

### Automating data entries

An **easier way of achieving what you want** is to use the [Form Response](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) methods from Apps Script Google Form´s documentation for [pre filling](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#toprefilledurl) the form. This piece of code will automate data entries from google´s spreadsheet:

```js
function auto_data_entry(){

  var url='YOUR FORM URL';
  
  var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wrkSht= wrkBk.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  
  var Transaction1 = wrkSht.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var Transaction2 = wrkSht.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var Transaction3 = wrkSht.getRange("A3").getValue();
  var Transaction4 = wrkSht.getRange("A4").getValue();
  var Transaction5 = wrkSht.getRange("A5").getValue();
 
  var data = [Transaction1,Transaction2,Transaction3,Transaction4,Transaction5];


  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(url);
  var questions = form.getItems(); //get the different questions you want to pre fill
  var FormResponse = form.createResponse();
  //set a response from your response data array to the corresponding question until you fill the whole form
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    var qt = questions[i].asTextItem(); 
    var qr = qt.createResponse(data[i]);
    FormResponse.withItemResponse( qr ); 
  }
  //create a prefilled form
  var preurl = FormResponse.toPrefilledUrl();
  Logger.log(preurl);
  
}
```

> NOTE: your pre filled form url is in the log.

### Automating form submissions

Also, if you wish to automate form [submissions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#submit) from your spreadsheet data you can use this code:

```js
function auto_submission() {
   
  var url='YOUR FORM URL';
  
  var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wrkSht= wrkBk.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  
  var Transaction1 = wrkSht.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var Transaction2 = wrkSht.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var Transaction3 = wrkSht.getRange("A3").getValue();
  var Transaction4 = wrkSht.getRange("A4").getValue();
  var Transaction5 = wrkSht.getRange("A5").getValue();
  
  var data = [Transaction1,Transaction2,Transaction3,Transaction4,Transaction5];
  

  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(url);
  var questions = form.getItems(); //get the different questions you want to fill
  var FormResponse = form.createResponse();
  //set a response from your response data array to the corresponding question until you fill the whole form
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    var qt = questions[i].asTextItem(); 
    var qr = qt.createResponse(data[i]);
    FormResponse.withItemResponse( qr ); 
  }
  //submit the form
  FormResponse.submit();

}
```

I hope this has helped you, let me know if you found any issues or if you do not understand anything.